# TypeError : Cannot set property 'innertext' of null

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a JavaScript calculator application. Currently, when pressing on the buttons, I get this error:

> Uncaught `TypeError`: Cannot set property '`innerText`' of `null`

Here is my code:

```js
class Calculator {
  constructor(previousOperandTextElement, currentOperandTextElement) {
    this.previousOperandTextElement = previousOperandTextElement;
    this.currentOperandTextElement = currentOperandTextElement;
    this.clear();
  }
  clear() {
    this.currentOperand = '';
    this.previousOperand = '';
    this.operation = '';
  }
  delete() {}
  appendNumber(number) {
    this.currentOperand = this.currentOperand.toString() + number.toString();
  }
  chooseOperation(operation) {}
  computer() {}
  updateDisplay() {
    this.currentOperandTextElement.innerText = this.currentOperand;
  }
}
const numberButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-number]');
const operationButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-operation]');
const equalsButton = document.querySelector(['data-equals']);
const allClearButton = document.querySelector(['data-all-clear']);
const previousOperandTextElement = document.querySelector(['data-previousOperand']);
const currentOperandTextElement = document.querySelector(['data-currentOperand']);
const calculator = new Calculator(previousOperandTextElement, currentOperandTextElement)
numberButtons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    calculator.appendNumber(button.innerText)
    calculator.updateDisplay()
  })
})
```

```html
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
 <title>Calculator</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
 </head>
  <body>
     <div class="calculator-grid">
    <div class="output">
        <div data-previousOperand class="previous-operand"></div>
        <div data-currentOperand class="current-operand"></div>
    </div>
    <button data-all-clear class="span-two">AC</button>
    <button data-delete>Del</button>
    <button data-operation>/</button>
    <button data-number>1</button>
    <button data-number>2</button>
    <button data-number>3</button>
    <button data-operation>*</button>
    <button data-number>4</button>
    <button data-number>5</button>
    <button data-number>6</button>
    <button data-operation>+</button>
    <button data-number>7</button>
    <button data-number>8</button>
    <button data-number>9</button>
    <button data-operation>-</button>
    <button data-number>.</button>
    <button data-number>0</button>
    <button data-equals class="span-two">=</button>
    </div>
    <script src="js/index.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Howdy, welcome to SO! Mind sharing the parts we need to actually troubleshoot since just your HTML doesn't provide a reproducible example?

Comment: sounds like `currentOperandTextElement` is null. Simple console.log will verify it.

Comment: The error is because you are trying to set the inner text to an element using **this** but in your function you are not telling from where comes **this** please check this link to the correct usage of this https://medium.com/better-programming/understanding-the-this-keyword-in-javascript-cb76d4c7c5e8

Comment: @ChrisW. I've edited it now.

Comment: @User1899289003 not a this issue

Answer (score 1):

`currentOperandTextElement` is not Element type. Before using `innerText`, check if currentOperandTextElement is created from Element.

```
updateDisplay() {
  if ( this.currentOperandTextElement instanceof Element ) {
    this.currentOperandTextElement.innerText = this.currentOperand;
  }
}
```

Or put in constructor next construction for easily debug code, which called `new Calculator`:

```
constructor(previousOperandTextElement, currentOperandTextElement) {
  if ( ! currentOperandTextElement instanceof Element ) {
    console.error('new Calculator: argument 2 must be instance of Element');
  }

  this.previousOperandTextElement = previousOperandTextElement;
  this.currentOperandTextElement = currentOperandTextElement;
  this.clear();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `document.querySelector` wrongly.
Instead of `document.querySelector(['data-currentOperand'])` do `document.querySelector('[data-currentOperand]')`.

Square brackets inside quotes.

That's why you can not find an element and get `null`. Change everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

If you add console.log lines after where you reference your elements, you will find they are not finding them. So when you are initializing your calculator, you are passing in null values.

When you use data attributes. You should not be using camel case in the names. You should space out each with with a dash.

So use `<div data-previous-operand ...` and look for `querySelector('[data-previous-operand]')`. You should do the same with `data-currentOperand`